# How to use multiple directory for angular js templates? Using grails angular template asset pipeline plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails, angular-template

We want to have a project structure like this:

```
assets/javascripts/
  - featureA/
       - templateA.html
       - controllerA.js
  - featureB/
       - templateB.html
       - controllerB.js
```

But the angular template asset pipeline plugin only accepts one directory/folder on its config for the templates.

```
grails {
    assets {
        angular {
            templateFolder = 'templates'
            moduleNameBase = 'app'
            compressHtml = true
            preserveHtmlComments = false
            includePathInName = false
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anyway for the plugin to be able to scan the nested folders under the given template folder?

Comment: We have a controller that does the packaging of angular templates for us (is heavily cached so there's no performance penalty). I'm not sure whether I'd recommend that approach personally though :-)